# Bash correct (?) if statement not executing properly

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am sourcing the shell script of a software but I keep receiving the following error:

```
>source thefile.sh
'else' builtin not inside of if block
```

I've checked the theoretically erroneous block and I can't find anything wrong with the structure

```
if [ condition ]
then 
if [ condition2 ]
then
dostuff
else
dostuffagain
fi
else # this is the else which generates the error
stuffstuffstuff
fi
```

I can't see anything wrong with it: it's a nested if/then and every if is terminated by it's own fi. Why the shell gets upset about it??

Comment: Does `thefile.sh` execute without error when directly executed? It might be a valuable information, as for example shebangs are ignored when sourcing

Comment: replacing `condition` and `stuff` with something meaningful, your example works for me.

Comment: check the whole file at http://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: Look for unbalanced (double) quotes and braces in `dostuffagain`.

Comment: @Robin479, unfortunately I cannot put what's in conditions and stuff, since it's from a software I'm not developing and therefore I do not want to show any "true" code. Anyhow @Aaron you were right: if I run `./thefile.sh` I do not receive any errors. How can I source it, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a `bash` error message; I found it in the [source code for the `fish` shell](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/src/parse_tree.cpp):

```
 case parse_keyword_else: {
                this->parse_error(token, parse_error_unbalancing_else,
                                  L"'else' builtin not inside of if block");
```

This tells me you're trying to `source` a `bash` script in a `fish` shell, which is not going to work. `source` tells the shell (`fish` in this case) to execute the script itself, but the `fish` shell's syntax is too different from the `bash` syntax used in the script for it to make sense.

(I suppose you could try to write a [polyglot script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) that'd work in both `bash` and `fish`, but this would be difficult.)

Comment: you're right, I wasn't realizing that I was still inside a fish shell! Thanks